# Scala trait `this.type` in type parameter

Tags: scala, inheritance, traits

Have a look at these two simple traits:

```
trait TreeNode1[S] {
    def subNodes: List[S]
}
trait TreeNode2 {
    def subNodes: List[this.type]
}
```

*(Not best naming, renamed them just to be brief.)*
`TreeNode1` defines a tree node with its children access, pointing their type `S`.
`TreeNode2` defines the same, but its children have the same type as the class the current trait is mixed in (another words, tree node with uniform subnodes).

In theory **`TreeNode2` is a particular case of `TreeNode1`**:

```
trait TreeNode2 extends TreeNode1[this.type] {...}
```

But **Scala will not compile `TreeNode2`** with such an extension, because `this.type` can not be used in such way, although there are no any inconsistencies with its working in runtime.

How can I get around this situation? Or Scala do not offer such poorly used mechanism?

---

*The reason I need this construction is the following:*

I have another trait that requires `TreeNode1` to be mixed in. I also have some class that mixes `TreeNode1` with quite another children type. But I also have several classes which have the same type as they are:

```
class SomeTreeNode extends TreeNode1[SomeTreeNode]
```

So it will look prettier if I use `TreeNode2` for it:

```
class SomeTreeNode extends TreeNode2
```

Implementing the same logic. But for using `TreeNode2` should be a case of `TreeNode1`, which it actually is, but Scala doesn't agree with me.

P.S. At least it is wondering as theoretical question about Scala, not for a wide practical use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> its children have the same type as the class the current trait is mixed

No. This is a common misunderstanding. `this.type` is the singleton type of `this`; i.e. [the type whose only two values are `this` and `null`](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.12/03-types.html#singleton-types). All children of a `TreeNode2` instance must be the same instance.

To answer the other part of your question, one option is to make `S` a type member instead of a type parameter:

```
trait TreeNode1 {
    type S
    def subNodes: List[S]
}
object TreeNode1 {
    // use TreeNode1.Aux[S] where you had TreeNode1[S] originally
    type Aux[T] = TreeNode1 { type S = T }
}

trait TreeNode2 {
    type S = this.type // not really what you want
    def subNodes: List[this.type]
}
```

(so-called `Aux` pattern), but whether this works for you depends on how they are used.