# Why is this requiring an existential type that is expanding to include Singleton?

Tags: scala, generics, existential-type, type-members

In this Scala 2.13 example:

```scala
import scala.language.implicitConversions

object Main extends App {

  trait Choosable {
    type T
    type Choose = this.type => T
    @inline implicit def choice(choose: Choose): T = choose(this)
  }

  object Choosable {
    implicit class ChooseOps[C <: Choosable](private val choose: C#Choose) extends AnyVal {
      def display(implicit choice: C#Choose => C#T): String = choice(choose).toString
    }
  }

  object Color extends Choosable {
    override type T = String
    val Red: T = "Red"
    val Blue: T = "Blue"
  }

  def displayChosenColor(color: Color.Choose): Unit = {
    println(Choosable.ChooseOps[Color.type](color).display(Color.choice))
  }

  displayChosenColor(_.Red)
}
```

It fails with:

```
type mismatch;
 found   : Main.Color.Choose => Main.Color.T
    (which expands to)  (Main.Color.type => String) => String
 required: (_1.type => _1.T forSome { val _1: Main.Color.type }) => Main.Color.T
    (which expands to)  (Function1[_ <: Main.Color.type with Singleton, String]) => String
    println(Choosable.ChooseOps[Color.type](color).display(Color.choice))
```

Why is an existential type?

Why is that existential type expanding to `(Function1[_ <: Main.Color.type with Singleton, String]) => String`?

Is there a way too get `display` to require a `Main.Color.Choose => Main.Color.T`?

---

This Q&A ([Scala trait `this.type` in type parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50592561/scala-trait-this-type-in-type-parameter)) gives some clues that it might have something to do with `this.type`.

I get that `this.type` is the Singleton type which denotes the set containing only `this`.

In my case, `C` is `Color.type` which denotes the set containing only `Color`.

We can see from the error that `Color.choice` has the type `(Main.Color.type => String) => String`.

The thing that I don't get is the existential type `_1.type => _1.T forSome { val _1: Main.Color.type }`. Why is that not the same as `Main.Color.type => String`?

Comment: My current workaround is to add an additional abstract `type Self` and `def self: Self` to `Choosable`. It increases the burden on the implementations but the call sites work.

Comment: Bugs should be reported here https://github.com/scala/bug/issues